# VBA Code keeping too many workbooks open causing RAM issue

Tags: excel, vba, memory

The purpose of this code is to look for specific words at the top of each sheet and create a workbook based on those words found. The code then adds every sheet with the same name to the new workbook created that way. My problem is that about 175 or more workbooks need created this way and the code is doing that, but it is keeping too many workbooks open, which causes my pc to run out of RAM causing a memory issue. I need each new workbook to be closed after the necessary sheets are added form the original workbook. I know there has to be a way to get the workbooks to save and close after the necessary sheets have been copied over, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub Save()

 Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook`
 Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
 Dim SearchRange As Range
 Dim Cell As Range
 Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
 Dim NewWorksheet As Worksheet
 Dim FoundWords As Boolean
 Dim regex As Object
 Dim match As Object
 Dim SheetNames As Object
 Dim SheetName As String

   ' Set the source workbook and worksheet
   Set SourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

 ' Create a regular expression object
 Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 regex.Pattern = "\((\w+)\)$" ' Pattern to match any word enclosed in parentheses at the end of        a cell

' Create a dictionary to hold unique sheet names
Set SheetNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
For Each SourceWorksheet In SourceWorkbook.Sheets
    ' Reset flag for each sheet
    FoundWords = False
    
    ' Define the search range in the source worksheet
    Set SearchRange = SourceWorksheet.Range("A1:O3")
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the search range
    For Each Cell In SearchRange
        ' Check if the cell contains the desired word enclosed in parentheses at the end
        If regex.Test(Cell.Value) Then
            ' Get the match object
            Set match = regex.Execute(Cell.Value)(0)
            
            FoundWords = True ' Set flag to indicate that words were found
            
            ' Check if a new workbook has been created for this set of found words
            If SheetNames.exists(match.SubMatches(0)) Then
                ' Copy the entire source worksheet to a new worksheet in the existing new workbook
                SheetName = SheetNames(match.SubMatches(0))
                SourceWorksheet.Copy After:=Workbooks(SheetName).Sheets(Workbooks(SheetName).Sheets.count)
            Else
                ' Create a new workbook
                Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
                Set NewWorksheet = NewWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                
                ' Copy the entire source worksheet to the new worksheet in the new workbook
                SourceWorksheet.Copy Before:=NewWorksheet
                
                ' Delete the default blank sheet in the new workbook
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Disable alerts to prevent prompt
                NewWorkbook.Sheets(2).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' Re-enable alerts
                
                ' Save the new workbook with a name based on the words found
                NewWorkbookName = "NewWorkbook_" & match.SubMatches(0) & ".xlsx" ' Update with your desired naming convention
                NewWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\JGuy\OneDrive - Redwood Living, Inc\Documents\Lender Reporting\Automation\Output Test\" & NewWorkbookName
                SheetNames.Add match.SubMatches(0), NewWorkbook.Name ' Add the sheet name to the dictionary
                
            End If
            
       
            
            ' Exit the loop after first set of found words
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Cell
    
    ' Display a message box if no words were found in the sheet
    If Not FoundWords Then
        MsgBox "No words found in the specified range in " & SourceWorksheet.Name, vbInformation
    End If
    
    ' Reset new worksheet reference
    Set NewWorksheet = Nothing
Next SourceWorksheet

' Close all new workbooks
For Each WB In Workbooks
If Left(WB.Name, 11) = "NewWorkbook" Then ' Check if the workbook name starts with "NewWorkbook"
    WB.Close False ' Close the workbook without saving changes
End If
Next WB

' Clean up objects
Set SourceWorksheet = Nothing
Set SourceWorkbook = Nothing
Set SearchRange = Nothing
Set NewWorksheet = Nothing
Set NewWorkbook = Nothing
Set SheetNames = Nothing
Set regex = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: When I do that, it causes a "subscript out of range" error on this line:

                    SourceWorksheet.Copy After:=Workbooks(SheetName).Sheets(Workbooks(SheetName).Sheets.count)

Comment: I tried it at many various places from where I showed you to below. It always throws an error at the same line. No matter where I place the newworkbook.close line, it always seems to throw an error on that same line I mentioned earlier. Thanks for your help with this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be cleaner to first collect all of the found words and associated sheets, and then create the workbooks one-by-one, saving and closing as you go.

```vb
Sub Save()

    Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook, SourceWorksheet As Worksheet, Cell As Range, wb As Workbook
    Dim NewWorksheet As Worksheet, FoundWords As Boolean, regex As Object, match As Object
    Dim AllWords As Object, wsName As String, wd As String, itm, k
   
    Set SourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = "\((\w+)\)$" 'any word enclosed in parentheses at the end of a cell

    Set AllWords = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    AllWords.comparemode = 1 'vbTextCompare: case-insensitive
    
    'loop the sheets and store all found words along with the sheets they were found on
    For Each SourceWorksheet In SourceWorkbook.Sheets
        FoundWords = False
        wsName = SourceWorksheet.name
        
        For Each Cell In SourceWorksheet.Range("A1:O3").Cells
            If regex.Test(Cell.value) Then
                
                Set match = regex.Execute(Cell.value)(0)
                wd = match.SubMatches(0)
                FoundWords = True ' Set flag to indicate that words were found
                
                If Not AllWords.exists(wd) Then AllWords.Add wd, New Collection 'create new key and Collection
                On Error Resume Next             'ignore error on duplicate key if sheet already added
                AllWords(wd).Add wsName, wsName  'add with key
                On Error GoTo 0                  'stop ignoring errors
            End If
        Next Cell
        
        ' Display a message box if no words were found in the sheet
        If Not FoundWords Then
            MsgBox "No words found in the specified range in " & wsName, vbInformation
        End If
    Next SourceWorksheet
    
    'now loop the dictionary and create a workbook for each word, copying the required sheets
    For Each k In AllWords
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'single sheet
        For Each itm In AllWords(k)
            SourceWorkbook.Sheets(itm).copy after:=wb.Sheets(1)
        Next itm
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Sheets(1).Delete 'remove initial sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\JGuy\OneDrive - Redwood Living, Inc\Documents\Lender Reporting\" & _
                "Automation\Output Test\NewWorkbook_" & k & ".xlsx"
        wb.Close False
    Next k
                
End Sub
```

Comment: If this helps, please mark as "Accepted", to help anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

Comment: You are amazing! This worked! If I wanted to order the sheets that are copied to the new workbooks in a specific way, how would I go about that, if you don't mind? I appreciate your help very much on this!

Comment: I guess that would depend on exactly what you mean by "some specific way"?  Right now they're added in the same order they exist in the source workbook.

Comment: I want them ordered based on either their sheet name or by a word found in the same cell range A1:O3. I figure doing it based on a word in their sheet name would be easiest as they all have the same words in their sheet names. One is a "balance sheet", next is an "income statement", next is a "12 month statement", and last is a "rent roll". So the words I would use to make the command order them would be to order by the words: Balance, Income, 12 Month, Rent. The order would be the same (1st sheet: Balance), (2nd sheet: Income), (3rd sheet: 12 Month), (4th sheet: Rent).

Comment: Those 4 are the only sheets?

Comment: So, what this macro is doing is going through a workbook that has roughly 650 sheets total. The macro makes a workbook and adds the worksheet that goes with the correct workbook, based on the words found cell range (A1:O3). Each workbook has 4 sheets that go with it. The macro correctly makes all the workbooks I need, but the order of the sheets in those workbooks is incorrect.

Comment: Are the sheets in the source workbook in the correct order?  If yes then you just need a small change: `SourceWorkbook.Sheets(itm).copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)`

Comment: I used Chatgpt to figure it out and got it to work. Thank you so much for your help. I used chatgpt for most of this project, but chatgpt was not able to figure out the part that you figured out so I really appreciate your help. I will mark this as answered now.